# Is it possible to install ubuntu on SUN FIRE X4270 Server

Tags: server

Is it possible to install ubuntu on SUN FIRE X4270 Server? if yes, what ubuntu version is possible to install

Comment: A google search says that the server has an Intel Xeon processor, so that should work. Try making a live/install media (USB or DVD) and boot on it to see if Ubuntu runs.Any Ubuntu version should do.

Comment: Understood, but I am afraid of drivers compatibility also I have Sun StorageTek attached to the server.